# CCXT how to get time transfer

Tags: python, cryptocurrency, ccxt

does someone know how to get the time of a transfer with the CCXT library for python,
if possible?
i can't find it in the documentation
there is another library for this?

Answer (score 0):

```
import ccxt
import sys
import json
from pprint import pprint

print('python', sys.version)
print('CCXT Version:', ccxt.__version__)

exchange = ccxt.binance({
    'apiKey': '...',
    'secret': '...',
})

pprint(exchange.fetch_transfers(params={
    'fromAccount': 'spot', 
    'toAccount': 'future'
}))
```

---

This is the method header

```
def fetchTransfers(code=None, since=None, limit=None, params={})
```